# Efficacy and costs of medical treatments

Tags: statistics, effectiveness, reference-request, public-health

There is an easy to grasp formula which combines the efficacy and the costs of a medical treatment, however these may be determined. I wonder if this formula (and the approach) has a name, and which role it plays in public health economics. The bigger context surely is [cost-effectiveness analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost-effectiveness_analysis) and its special case [cost-benefit analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost%E2%80%93benefit_analysis).

Consider the following scenario: There is a population in which at any time some N individuals suffer from some disease X ("patients"). Let there be an established therapy or treatment T<sub>1</sub> (pharmaceutical or other) which costs c<sub>1</sub> per patient. Let there be a new therapy T<sub>2</sub> with efficacy ε which costs c<sub>2</sub> per patient. Efficacy ε shall mean that a proportion ε of patients is cured by the therapy. Let all patients receive a treatment, either T<sub>1</sub> only (scenario 1), or first T<sub>2</sub> and only if it doesn't help T<sub>1</sub> (scenario 2).

Note that for our purposes c<sub>1</sub> may as well be considered the subsequent costs per patient when there is no treatment T<sub>1</sub> at all and T<sub>2</sub> is the first treatment in the market.

The total costs in the two scenarios are:

- C<sub>1</sub> = N · c<sub>1</sub>
- C<sub>2</sub> = N · c<sub>2</sub> + N ·  (1 - ε) · c<sub>1</sub>

Normalizing with respect to N and c<sub>1</sub>, i.e. N → 1, c<sub>1</sub> → 1, c<sub>2</sub> → c<sub>2</sub>/c<sub>1</sub> gives

- C<sub>1</sub> = 1
- C<sub>2</sub> = c<sub>2</sub> + (1 - ε)

The additional costs of scenario 2 compared to scenario 1 are

- ΔC = C<sub>2</sub> - C<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>2</sub> - ε

where c<sub>2</sub> and ε are dimensionless numbers which it makes sense to compare.

If c<sub>2</sub> > ε ("the costs are higher than the efficacy") scenario 2 may be considered uneconomical, if c<sub>2</sub> < ε ("the costs are lower than the efficacy") it may be considered economical.

Next to the difference c<sub>2</sub> - ε one may consider the ratio ε / c<sub>2</sub> as the cost-effectiveness of treatment T<sub>2</sub>.

Starting from these considerations one may take into account:

- other benefits of a treatment than monetary ones, e.g. [quality-adjusted life years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality-adjusted_life_year)
- [marginal costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_cost) c<sub>2</sub> instead of costs at some given point in time

To repeat my question from above:

- Where, in which disguise and under which name can I find these considerations (based on ΔC) in textbooks on health economics or the literature?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking what the general term for &Delta;C is? Do any of these help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_Economic_Analysis#Topical_outline ?

Comment: @JMP: Thanks for the hint. Does this book still play a role, e.g. in education? Yes, it's about &Delta;C - but as a difference between a (relative) price and an efficiacy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis looks similar to:

> [Incremental Cost-Effectiveness Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_cost-effectiveness_ratio) (ICER)

which:

> ICER ... is used in cost-effectiveness analysis to summarise the cost-effectiveness of a health care intervention. It is defined by the difference in cost between two possible interventions, divided by the difference in their effect.

In your case, because of your normalization, ε is effectively a measure of relative cost, and so the denominator is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "Incremental Cost-Effectiveness Ratio". This helps a lot for searching. Please note that ε is a measure of efficiacy: it gives the proportion of patients that are "cured" by therapy T2. But now I see that I implicitly set the efficiacy of therapy T1 to 1 - so there was no follow-up therapy needed as in the case of  therapy T2. I should work it over.